# Conditionally extracting Pandas rows based on another Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes:

`df1:`

```
col1    col2
1       2
1       3
2       4
```

`df2:`

```
col1
2
3
```

I want to extract all the rows in `df1` where `df1`'s `col2` `not in` `df2`'s `col1`. So in this case it would be:

```
col1    col2
2       4
```

I first tried:

```
df1[df1['col2'] not in df2['col1']]
```

But it returned:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I then tried:

```
df1[df1['col2'] not in df2['col1'].tolist]
```

But it returned:

> TypeError: argument of type 'instancemethod' is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for inverting boolean mask:

```
print (df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1']))
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: col2, dtype: bool

print (~df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1']))
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: col2, dtype: bool

print (df1[~df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])])
   col1  col2
2     2     4
```

**Timings**:

```
In [8]: %timeit (df1.query('col2 not in @df2.col1'))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.57 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit (df1[~df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])])
1000 loops, best of 3: 466 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

using [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

```
In [9]: df1.query('col2 not in @df2.col1')
Out[9]:
   col1  col2
2     2     4
```

Timing for bigger DFs:

```
In [44]: df1.shape
Out[44]: (30000000, 2)

In [45]: df2.shape
Out[45]: (20000000, 1)

In [46]: %timeit (df1[~df1['col2'].isin(df2['col1'])])
1 loop, best of 3: 5.56 s per loop

In [47]: %timeit (df1.query('col2 not in @df2.col1'))
1 loop, best of 3: 5.96 s per loop
```